# How to mimic function space

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, function

I came to this thought on last week. I am involved in creating an app which can analyze 200GB of log files with the given regex and make the report as CSV files. So multi threading is obvious. But even though we programmatically use multi threading like the below

```
lock(Object)
{
  //Logic
}//unlock(Object) if you prefer c++
```

It still has only one memory block in reality. Is there any way that I can make many memory space like that, so I can operate variables on those function spaces. And all those function spaces have the same functionality. The below picture can explain it properly

[image]

Note: Even delegate and anonymous functions also a single function/memory block.

**EDIT1:**
      I am interested in knowing whether "the title" is possible or not. I gave the problem to give you an idea of how I got this idea.

**EDIT2:**
     I think that in most of the languages there will be always only one instance for any function. This law goes everywhere including threading. I want many instances for a same function.

Comment: The question seems rather unclear to me. Are you asking how to create per-thread variables?

Comment: It kind of sounds like feeding 1000 sharks to one fish.

Comment: Is the data in the log-file of fixed size? Or is each record of variable size?

Comment: @Joachim The data is not in the fixed size. But the focus here is not the problem I am solving , rather the idea I came across.

Comment: *If* the data was fixed size, it would be easy to just divide the data into smaller chunks, one per thread. But like other have said, it's not very clear *exactly* what your solution is, do you want each thread to have its *own* copy of the 200GB data? Or do you want to split the data up in smaller chunks for the threads?

Comment: When you invoke a function, it has its own copy of any local data. So it's like "Class -> Instance. Function -> Function call" already. If that's not it, please post some example code of what you're doing, explain why it doesn't suit you and what you'd like to do instead.

Comment: @Angew when ever you instantiate an object it actually creates new members. But for functions, whether you are creating 100 or 1000 objects still you are having only one function instance. I want to create the function instances like object members.

Comment: @whoever voted to close. Put your thoughts rather than some blind close vote. I think you didn't even understand the question. This is a serious question.

Comment: @Joachim I want every thread to use a function, and all those functions must have the same functionality. and this must be driven dynamically. That means I should not hard code all those functions. Because every function does the same. So I will create a single function. then I will instatiate further functions out of it.

Comment: @prabhakaran Do you understand that every invocation of a function will have its own copy of any local variables? This means that if 10 threads execute `foo()`, each thread will have its own copy of `foo()`'s local variables. Can you explain clearly what you'd gain from having two (or ten) identical functions?

Comment: Regarding the vote to close (not mine, btw): there are several people here trying to figure out what you're asking about, so a vote to put on hold as "unclear what you're asking" doesn't seem so out of place. You'll have to explain yourself better.

Comment: @prabhakaran Regarding your `EDIT2`, you fail to explain why having only one "instance" of a function (it's not really an instance, functions are not instantiated) causes any problems. As mentioned, each thread will have a separate copy of local variables. What would  you possibly gain by duplicating the function?

Comment: @Rotem There was one. Now I can't remember it exactly. I will come back after I made some analysis.

Answer (score 2):

> It still has only one memory block in reality.

This assumption is incorrect. Calling a function will push all the local variables of that function onto the thread local stack.

In effect, what you get is similar to what you describe in the illustration titled `What I am Saying`.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Functions_of_the_call_stack) (emphasis mine):

> **Local data storage**
>   A subroutine frequently needs memory space for
>   storing the values of local variables, the variables that are known
>   only within the active subroutine and do not retain values after it
>   returns. It is often convenient to allocate space for this use by
>   simply moving the top of the stack by enough to provide the space.
>   This is very fast compared to heap allocation. **Note that each separate
>   activation of a subroutine gets its own separate space in the stack
>   for locals**.